# Programmatic sdcard mounting/unmounting

Tags: android

I'm wondering how programmatic sdcard mounting/unmounting can be achieved while the handset is connected to a pc via USB.

I cannot find any managed api for that and also my jni attempts failed with **errno: 1, [Operation not permitted]** error.

Thanks

Comment: There is an app for it, don't know how they are doing it. https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jrtstudio.automount&hl=en

Comment: Similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716105/how-can-i-mount-sdcard-programmatic

Answer (score 1):

It's no possible as one of the Android SDK engineers stated here: http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg27542.html

Comment: How doubleTwist Player does it (automatically mounting). Player doesn't require phone to be rooted. Found many posts where ppl complain or mention about this automatic mounting.  http://lifehacker.com/5584889/install-doubletwist-player-for-automatic-android-usb-mounting