# How to find the location of sdcard

Tags: java, php, android, database, sd-card

when i was checking an android app...I found that the videos in the app is uploaded in an sdcard..for ex:mnt/sdcard...is there an way to find the url of this sdcard....because...my need is to report this illegal content..is there any way please help....I gone through but i didn't get a proper answer...please help..
[how can i mount sdcard programmatic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716105/how-can-i-mount-sdcard-programmatic?rq=1)

[Programmatic sdcard mounting/unmounting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357282/programmatic-sdcard-mounting-unmounting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Mount SDCARD Programatically..

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
 Uri.parse("file://" +  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

---

find Location of file is simple:

i have video in my sdcard/my folder name/video then path is

```
File videoPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/myFolderName/video1.mp4");
```

---

### check external stroge available or not??

```
boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    // We can read and write the media
    mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
} else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
    // We can only read the media
    mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
    mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
} else {
    // Something else is wrong. It may be one of many other states, but all we need
    //  to know is we can neither read nor write
    mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) {
File f = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

This will give you External storage path.You can also use this:"/mnt/sdcard"
If still not clear then take a look at this link:[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694933/find-an-external-sd-card-location)

Hope this will help you.